# Example (keras) for custom image data generator(with augmentation) on google colab TPU

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory, tpu, google-cloud-tpu

I wrote a resnet-based model with Keras, train on image data with augmentation. I intend to use google colab TPU, but all examples I could found do not work, can anyone show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this example? https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tpu.ipynb

The notebook has some augmentation (`data_augment` method) and to use some resnet you can replace the model with `tf.keras.applications.ResNet50`.